# How to use HTTP POST to upload a multipart file

Tags: ruby, request, http-post

I need to send a POST with my headers and also a param called "_token" inside my request body as well as the image I want to upload.

This is the code that Postman is giving me but it never loads the file:

```
require 'uri' 
require 'net/http'

url = URI("https://myurl")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port) http.use_ssl = true http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url) 
request["content-type"] = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
request["cookie"] = 'mycookie'
request["cache-control"] = 'no-cache'
request["postman-token"] = '6031ee00-4553-6baf-c31c-c377a7185510'
request.body = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"_token\"\r\n\r\token\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"photo\";
filename=\"img.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

Comment: Don't use a comment to change the question. That forces us to read every comment and try to piece together the overall question. Instead, edit your question and add the information where it should have been initially. Please don't add "edited" or "updated" tags because we can see what changed and when if we need to. Also, SO isn't a discussion board, it's an online reference. Emoticons, greetings, valedictions and signatures aren't found in reference books so please refrain from using them in the question. Some informality is fine, but don't consider SO a discussion or social site.

Comment: Fixed sorry, I was looking for an edit button but I could not find it at the time.  Please delete this comment if everything is alright, and thanks for your help.

Comment: Note your edit now has an undesirable valediction "Thanks in advance" along with the `:|` emoticon which I'd edited out for you. I'd recommend reading "[ask]" along with the linked pages especially the last one. It's long but really helps people understand using a site like SO.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will improve my understanding of the site by reading the guide you have just provided me.

Comment: This is mycode now I can feel I am close to get it working but I am missing something. 

` url = URI(url)
File.open("./550948.jpg") do |jpg|
    req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new url.path,
        "file" => UploadIO.new(jpg, "image/jpeg", "550948.jpg") 
    req.add_field("cookie", hdr)
    req.set_form_data("_token" => token)     
    n = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port) 
    n.use_ssl = true
    n.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    res = n.start do |http|
        http.request(req)
        puts res
    end
end`

Comment: Please don't use comments to show changes to the code or the question. The formatting isn't good enough. Since there are no answers at this point it'd be OK to replace the code in the question. Normally you'd want to ask a new question if there were answers.